# Accessing user control properties defined in code behind in markup

Tags: asp.net

I have a public property defined in code behind of a user control. I want to toggle visibility of controls in the markup based on the property's value. However, using the 
following syntax:

```
<td  style="display:<%#(Container.PageControlMode == PageControlMode. PageMode.Wizard) ? "none" : "inline" %;">
```

I have the following property in my code behind:

```
public PageMode PageControlMode { get; set; }
```

Does not work and generate errors. What is a good way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a malformed closing `%>` tag. Place the semicolon before the percent symbol.

```
<td  style="display:<%#(Container.PageControlMode == PageControlMode. PageMode.Wizard) ? "none" : "inline";%>">
```